# ModuleNotFoundError in Colab

Tags: modulenotfounderror

Hi I want to install one package called 'scweet' on colab.

I tried this code below but does not work. I really do not know what is the issue. can anyone help me?

[Error Message Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJrfT.png)

git clone method also gives me same error.

`!git clone --quiet https://github.com/Altimis/Scweet.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact package name is 'Scweet' with a capital letter:)

```
!pip install scweet
import Scweet
```

Works just fine.